# Accessing array and getting different values than what was set

Tags: arrays, vb.net, types

I'm somewhat new to VB.NET.  I need to save a special type of data in an array.  I then use the data in other sub routines.  I wrote the below code as a sample to ask my question about it.

When printing or displaying the data from the array in the other methods, it does not give the correct values from what I set before!  What could be the reason for that.  What do I need to change to fix the problem?

```
Public Class Form1
    Private eList = New List(Of Boolean) From {True, True, True, False}
    Private eType = New List(Of String) From {"a1", "a2", "b1", "z"}
    Dim Dizi(0 To 1, 0 To 3) As ITEM
    Friend ITEM As ITEM

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim iA As ITEM = New ITEM

        For i = 0 To 3
            Dizi(0, i) = New ITEM
            Dizi(1, i) = New ITEM
        Next

        For i = 0 To 3
            iA.Enable = eList(i)
            iA.Type = eType(i)
            Dizi(0, i) = iA
            ' iA = Dizi.GetValue(0, i)  ' this for checking the setted value on the array cell.
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For i = 0 To 3
            Dizi(1, i) = Dizi(0, i)
        Next
        Debug.Print(Dizi(0, 2).Type & " " & Dizi(1, 2).Type)
    End Sub
End Class

Class ITEM
    Property Enable As Boolean
    Property Type As String
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is here:

```
For i = 0 To 3
    iA.Enable = eList(i)
    iA.Type = eType(i)
    Dizi(0, i) = iA
Next
```

What you probably wanted to do, instead, was either this:

```
For i = 0 To 3
    Dizi(0, i).Enable = eList(i)
    Dizi(0, i).Type = eType(i)
Next
```

Or this:

```
For i = 0 To 3
    iA = New ITEM()
    iA.Enable = eList(i)
    iA.Type = eType(i)
    Dizi(0, i) = iA
Next
```

Your confusion is likely from not properly understanding the difference between *value types* and *reference types*.  I would recommend doing some research to learn the difference between those two kinds of types.

In your code, you are setting `Dizi(0, 0)`, `Dizi(0, 1)`, `Dizi(0, 2)`, and `Dizi(0, 3)` to  all reference the same object (the same `ITEM` instance which is referenced by `iA`).  Since `ITEM` is a reference type (a `Class`, as opposed to a `Structure`), when you set one `ITEM` variable equal to another `ITEM` variable, it does **not** make a copy of the object.  It only copies the reference to the same object.  In other words, when the `ITEM` properties are set via one variable, the same changes are automatically and immediately reflected in the other variable.  That doesn't happen because the changes are automatically copied to all the variables.  It happens because both variables are essentially two different names for the same object.